# Using movenext and moveprevious

Tags: vb.net, adodb

I want to get the next value of the field next to the current row.

I used ADODB movenext and moveprevious together, but there is an error that the current context does not permitted.

How to fix that?

This is the code

```
objresultset.MoveNext()
yMark = objresultset.Fields(k1).Value
If xMark = yMark Then
    m += 1
End If
objresultset.MovePrevious()
```

Comment: ADODB is quite old. If you can switch to ADO.net and check out the BindingNavigator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. Perhaps you provide too little information.

I assume that ADO recordset features might also dependent upon the underlying database system and/or your database connection properties. So perhaps your specific database/recordset instance does not support MovePrevious in your case.

But if it has worked before, or if it works in a small test application, perhaps you are trying to move beyond the last record in your recordset. In that case you might check the BOF/EOF property values before you try to use MovePrevious/MoveNext.